Product search by image using Vision API
I'd like to search for products from particular websites using a user-chosen image. E.g. the user chooses an image of a shirt, the search returns pages of products on certain ecommerce websites with visually similar images. I've seen this done elsewhere, e.g. in several browser extensions. But I'm having trouble finding the right API.
I've played around with Google Vision API. This includes (1) Vision API Product search, but that seems always to involve uploading your own products to your own product set and matching images against that set (not matching against the open web); and (2) Web Detection requests ( "type": "WEB_DETECTION" ) which does return pages containing similar images, but from anywhere - whereas I'd like to constrain the search to certain ecommerce websites. Yes, I could ask for a million results and filter, but I'd prefer a focused search in the first place.
Am I missing something about Google's Vision API or is there another API I should use?

You can't use google vision like that. You will need to use your own dataset. Your best bet is to scrap your respective website and then store it in bucket and then use product api.
